# How to set default show line number and white space in PhpStorm 2016.1

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How to make line number visible in PhpStorm 2016.1?

I can't find setting in preferences.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne for edited a correct spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CMD+SHIFT+A` (on Mac) to search for actions across the IDE, including the preference pane. In this instance, typing "Line Numbers" into the search box takes you right to the preference pane for that option, with it highlighted nicely for you (http://c.hock.in/17c45d.png). This works for any settings you can't find, or want to find quickly.

Answer (score 2):

`Preferences` if your are on Mac | `Editor` --> `(General)` --> Appearance --> Show line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

File->Setting->Editor->Appearance->show line numbers for Windows users

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

**PhpStorm 2016.1** for Active Editor only

**Main Menu:**
View -> Active Editor -> Show Line Numbers

===========================================

**2.**

**PhpStorm 2016.1** for all tabs

**Main Menu**
File -> Settings:
[image]